# GTK+ の TextView で1文字書かれるごとにコールバックしたい

Tags: c, gtk

textviewウィンドウで1文字書かれるごとコールバックしたいです。
シグナルは何にすればいいのですか?
どのようにすればいいのでしょうか?
ソースかリンクを書いてくれると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

用途にもよると思いますが、TextView で表示している [TextBuffer のシグナル](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#GtkTextBuffer.signals) ではどうでしょうか。
`changed` や `insert_text` があります。
ただ、貼り付け操作や、インプットメソッドの使用などがあるので、「挿入」は一文字ごとに行なわれるとは限りません。
一応コードも書いておきましたが、普通にシグナルハンドラを登録しているだけです。（Genie です。まあ、疑似コードと考えて下さい）

```
// print_text_buffer_signal.gs
// valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 print_text_buffer_signal.gs 

uses
    Gtk

init
    Intl.setlocale(LocaleCategory.ALL, "")
    Gtk.init(ref args)

    // ウィンドウ
    var win = new Gtk.Window()
    win.set_title("TextBuffer のシグナルのテスト")
    win.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit)

    // バッファ
    var buf = new Gtk.TextBuffer(null)
    buf.set_text("今日は、世界！\n")
    buf.changed.connect(changed_hdl)
    buf.insert_text.connect(insert_text_hdl)

    // ビュー
    var view = new Gtk.TextView.with_buffer(buf)
    win.add(view)

    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()


def changed_hdl()
    print "変更されました"

def insert_text_hdl(ref pos:TextIter, new_text:string, new_text_length:int)
    print @"挿入されました: $new_text"
```